# Convergence of series $\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{\sin^2(k\pi)}{k^2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> How can i prove that the series $$\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{\sin^2(k\pi)}{k^2}$$ converges (or do not).

What i tried

From comparison test

$$\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{\sin^2(k\pi)}{k^2}\leq\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{1}{k^2}$$

Now $\displaystyle \sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{1}{k^2}$  converges using $p$-series test.

Therefore the series is convergent.

But i have a doubt $\sin^2(k\pi)=0$ for all $k\geq 1$ where $k$ is integer.

So $$\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{\sin^2 k\pi}{k^2}=0$$

i.e directly the series is convergent.

Then what is the need for the comparison-test and the $p$-series test.

Please explain. Thanks

Comment: Yes, for this series, we don't need comparison test as it is trivially zero.

Comment: So can we say  directly hat series converge to $0$

Comment: Fortunately, yes.

Comment: What i have done camparision and $p$ series is also true. Plesse clearfy me.

Comment: Yes, what you have done is correct but it is not needed as series is zero.